# Ionic-V1 xcode project don't show image from input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem on my ionic V1 project with an input file, I'm trying to make an image preview in order to get mouse coordinates from user before send it to the server. When I'm running the code in browser using `ionic serve` everything work fine, but when i'm running it from an Iphone 6 device in Xcode simulator it doesn't show me the image. Does anyone know or had this problem?

Uploaded image from web browser

[image]

Uploaded image from iphone

[image]
My code looks like this
Upload Image Controller:

```
var ctrl = angular.module('uploadImageController', []);

ctrl.controller('uploadImageController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {
let $constructor = () => {
    $scope.coordonate = {};
    document.getElementById('imgPreview').onclick = function(e) {
        $scope.coordonate.x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        $scope.coordonate.y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
        document.getElementById('imgPreview').style = "display:none;";
    }
    document.getElementById('firstImage').onchange = function(evt) {
        var tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement,
            files = tgt.files;
        if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById('imgPreview').src = fr.result;
            }
            $scope.uploaded = 1;
            fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        } else {

        }
    }
}

$scope.add = function() {
    if ($scope.uploaded) {
        if ($scope.coordonate.x && $scope.coordonate.x) {
            alert($scope.coordonate.x)
            var f = document.getElementById('secondImage').files[0],
                r = new FileReader();
            console.log(f);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('secondImage', f);
            console.log("Add function");
            var f = document.getElementById('firstImage').files[0],
                r = new FileReader();
            console.log(f);
            formData.append('firstImage', f);
            formData.append('coordonatex', $scope.coordonate.x.toFixed(0));
            formData.append('coordonatey', $scope.coordonate.y.toFixed(0));
            document.getElementById('loader').style = "display:block;";
            document.getElementById('content').style = "display:none;";

            $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/uploadImage', data: formData, headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } }).then(function(response) {

                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById('loader').style = "display:none;";
                    document.getElementById('content').style = "display:block;";
                    $state.go('result', { img: response.data });
                }, 0);
            })
        } else {
            alert('Choose a point');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Choose an image');
    }
}



$constructor();
}])
```

HTML Template for uploadImage:

```
<!Doctype html>
<ion-view title="uploadImage">
<ion-content>
    <div id="loader" class="loader"></div>
    <div style="height: 90px"></div>
    <div class="animate-bottom" id="content">
        <div class="container-fuild" style="margin:auto; color:white;text-align:center;">
            <title>Upload new File</title>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Upload first image</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12"><img src="" id="imgPreview" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-5">
                    <input type="file" id="firstImage" name="file"/> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Upload second image</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-5">
                    <input type="file" id="secondImage" name="secondImage" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-5">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">Simulate</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced similar problem in apple devices, It was due to the Content Security Policy.
In index.html adding the below code helped me.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' gap: ; img-src * 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; media-src *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

The device calling gap:ready seems to be the issue. For that, include 'gap' in CSP as mentioned. Hope this helps you too.